# Playing ogg (codec opus) audio in audio player in Ionic 5

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, audio, capacitor, ogg

I have some .ogg audio files hosted on cloud and wanted to play in a audio player. The next code works fine on Android but not in iOS:

```
<audio controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="<ogg_audio_url>" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

I'm using Ionic 5 with Capacitor. I tried to use some Cordova plugins, convert the file to base64, but no success. From what I've read in some forums, iOS does not support playback of audios in ogg format, requiring specific applications, is there any way to do this in an Ionic way, using a cordova plugin or similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use native audio plugin for better compatibility.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio